# cheking if an asp.net webform is already running in the local browser or not before opening it again

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am developing an application, in which if I am closing a webform(child.aspx) , before closing that form, it has to check whether another web form(parent.aspx) is already running or not.If it is already running, it has to refresh that page.Otherwise it has to open that page.

Comment: Consider posting your attempt at this problem. It adds context to the question and make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this in javascript and not on asp.net, as both the child and parent are open on the client side and server would not control whether child is closed or not.

in your case i would suggest you to open child.aspx from parent.aspx in a modal dialog or a popup where you have control on the parent / child relationship